# Inductor impedance

Tags: ac, inductor, impedance

I feel like I'm missing/forgotten something fundamental with regards to impedances.

For an inductor \$X_L=2πfL\$, so for a 68uH at 500kHz \$X_L = 2π \times 500\text{ k} \times 68\text{ u} = 214Ω\$.

So $$\frac{16\text{ V}}{214Ω + 2 + 214Ω } = 37\text{ mA}$$

But, when I put it into a circuit like below, using LTSpice, and measure the current, it's behaving more like \$1Ω\$.

What am I missing?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEOSgT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What's the peak voltage of V1? Why are you using a square wave when your calculations were based on a sine wave?

Comment: You can't just add the 2 Ω of real impedance to the 417 Ω of imaginary impedance (inductor impedance is jωL, not just ωL). You need to do a vector sum. What's the saturation current of your inductors?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Added voltage to drawing, 16V.  Good point, but with a sine wave I still get 3.8Amps.  So my issue persists either way.

Comment: @Hearth I'm using "ideal" inductors in LTSpice.

Comment: I used the circuitlab simulator on your circuit as linked and got a peak resistor current of around 40mA on the graph, so your LTspice simulation is more suspect, not your math.

Comment: What DC level is associated with the signal input?

Comment: @Andyaka The signal, square wave or sine wave goes from 0V to 16V.

Comment: So you have an average value of 8 volts. Think about what I've just said.

Comment: @Andyaka Okay, that makes sense.  16V * 50% duty cycle = 8V.  And 8V/2Ω = 4A for the DC component.  While my original calculations were only calculating the AC component.

Comment: @Andyaka Last hump to get over, what am I missing on the sine wave version (3.8A)?  16Vpp = 8Vpk.  Vrms = .707 * 8Vpk = 5.656V.  5.656/2=2.8A not 3.8A.

Comment: @Aaron the .707 trick won't work as that's for 0 biased sines only, here's a reasonable web reference: https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/how-to-derive-the-rms-value-of-a-sine-wave-with-a-dc-offset/

Comment: @Bryan thanks for the link.  I'll start a new post for that one, cause it still isn't matching the 3.8A.

Answer (score 5):

LTspice shows the correct current, about 37.4 mA in both transient and AC analysis.

Perhaps your sine and square wave source wasn't centered around zero volts in which case you'll get a 4A DC current plus the AC current.

In transient analysis, you need to let the transient die out as shown in the simulation below. The left part of the graph shows the time from zero to 1ms. The right part is expanded from 975us to 1ms.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the case.  My input is from 0V to 16V p-p.  Or as a sine wave 8V amplitude with 8V offset.

Answer (score 1):

A square wave can be represented using Fourier Series as
$$
V_s(t)=\frac{A}{2}+\frac{2A}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sin(n\omega_0 t)
$$

where A is the amplitude of the square wave (16 V in this case) and
$$
n = 2k-1
$$

so, the current in your circuit is

$$
\textbf{I}_{o}=\frac{\textbf{V}_s}{R+j\omega_n L}
$$

where

$$
\omega_n = n\omega_0 = n(2\pi)(500 \times10^{3}) = n\pi 10^{6}\text{ rad/s}
$$

Therefore

$$
\textbf{I}_{o}=\frac{\textbf{V}_s}{R+j\omega_n L} = \frac{\textbf{V}_s}{2+jn(\pi\times 10^6)(136 \times 10^{-6})} = \frac{\textbf{V}_s}{2+j136n\pi} 
$$

For the dc component
$$
\omega_n = 0  \;\; or \;\; n = 0 \\
\textbf{V}_s = \frac{A}{2} = \frac{16}{2} = 8\text{ V} \\
\textbf{I}_o = \frac{\textbf{V}_s}{R} = \frac{8}{2}=4\text{ A}
$$

Edit

For the nth harmonic
$$\textbf{V}_s = \frac{2A}{n\pi}\angle{-90}^{\circ}$$

and the corresponding output is

$$
\textbf{I}_o = \frac{\textbf{V}_s}{2+j136n\pi} = \frac{2A \angle{-90}}{n\pi \sqrt{4+136^{2} n^{2} \pi ^{2} } \angle (tan^{-1}\frac{136n\pi}{2})}
$$

In the time domain, the complete output is

$$
i_O(t) = 4+ \frac{32}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \sqrt{4+136^{2} n^{2} \pi ^{2}}}\cos(n\pi t - tan^{-1} \frac{136n\pi}{2} )
$$